# Ring of Witt Vectors and Tensor product of Fields

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, witt-vectors

Let $p > 2$ be a prime, and let $\textbf{F}_{p} =
\textbf{Z}/p\textbf{Z}$. Let $k_{1}$ be a finite field over
$\textbf{F}_{p}$, and let $k$ be a perfect field of characteristic
$p$. Then we have ring isomorphism $k_{1} \otimes_{\textbf{F}_{p}} k
\cong \oplus_{i=1}^{n} l_{i}$ where $l_{i}$ are finite extensions of
$k$.

Question: How do we prove that $W(k_{1})
\otimes_{\textbf{Z}_{p}} W(k) \cong \oplus_{i=1}^{n} W(l_{i})$, where
$W(k)$ denote the ring of Witt vectors of $k$?

Any suggestions or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not true in general that when $k$ is finite you will always have $k\subset k_1$ or $k_1\subset k$.

Comment: @KevinVentullo: Oops, sorry. I was being stupid. But the above result is still true in that case. I edited my question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: A family of special cases, including the ones of interest to you, of an earlier, more general [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57323/tensor-product-of-witt-vectors) was addressed by [@WilberdvanderKallen](http://mathoverflow.net/a/57349/2383).